# Установка modx в ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, modx

Apache, MySqL, PHP - встанет сюда modx? Вопрос возник от суждения, что MySqL убираем, встанет лишь с MariaDB. Верно ли сие утверждение?

Comment: Уточните вопрос, почему вы считаете, что modx не встанет? в системных требованиях у него: Database  Minimum Recommended - Latest MySQL 5.5.x  Recommended for Production - MariaDB 10.1.x or Percona Server 5.6.x or above, у меня на ubuntu и MySQL прекрасно работает

Comment: Хочу установить Apache, MySqL, PHP в ubuntu и ставить modx. Просто услышал мнение, что если нет mariadb, то modx не встанет и не заработает; услышав усомнился, решил у народа спросить.

Comment: Все прекрасно работает.

Comment: Понятно, будем знать.